# Linear Difference Equation with Constant Coefficients-Solution

Tags: sequences-and-series

I seem to be unable to understand the steps of solving the following linear difference equation: x(n)-7x(n-1)+10x(n-2)=0, where x(0)=0 and x(1)=1.

Comment: Could you provide a few more details in terms of what you tried and what steps specifically prove to be difficult?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Make the ansatz $$x_n=q^n$$ and solve the equation for $q$.

Second hint: The result should be $$x_n=\frac{5^n-2^n}{3}$$